# How to reload a render in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, atom-editor

Hi guys I'm new to Reactjs. And I'm having difficulty in reloading my render when I click the delete button in modal. I want that after click the button , the render should reload without reloading the page.

Here are some of my codes:

```
render (
   ....
   <button className="btn btn-black btn-myproducts-delete"
data-toggle="modal" onClick={ this.assignId.bind(null, data.id) }>
<span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
&nbsp;Delete</button>
 )
```

My Modal

```
<Modal isOpen={ this.state.showModal }
            onRequestClose={ this.closeModal }
            style={customStyles}
            contentLabel="Delete">
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.closeModal}>&times;</button>
                        <h4 className="modal-title">Delete</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this?
                    You cannot undo this method.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger"
                    onClick={this.deleteProduct.bind(null, this.state.productId)}>Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.closeModal}>
                    Cancel
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </Modal>
```

and for delete

```
delete = (idd) => {
    const { actions } = this.props;

    actions.delete(id);
    this.setState({showModal: false});

    window.location.reload();
}
```

what should I do ?

Comment: using setState will call render(). No need to do window.location.reload();

Comment: thanks bro, i will do that

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where are you calling your function "delete". 
Anyway, in react, your component are updated when your state or your props change.
A `this.setState()` update your component.
If you want to update your component without change of state or props you can can `this.forceUpdate()`
I hope that can help :)